# In SQLite, how can I delete rows in one table correspoding to the index in another table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables A and B. A contains whole data. B contains only the index that should be deleted. How can I delete the corresponding data in A that has the same index in B.

For example, 
A is a table like:

[image: TABLE A]

B is a table like:

[image: TABLE B]

I should delete the rows in A with all the (x,y) pairs in B
and make A looks like this:

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried

Comment: Based on an error mentioned in a comment below, I changed the database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL (as the question was originally tagged) you can use `join`:

```
delete a
    from a join
         b
         using (x, y);
```

In SQLite or almost any other database, you can use:

```
delete 
    from a
    where exists (select 1 from b where b.x = a.x and b.y = a.y)
```

Comment: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "a": syntax error  Some error like this

Comment: The syntax is fine in MySQL:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2eb371edcd440a8a541618208eaae5f.  Your error is a SQLite error, so you have mistagged your question.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I have found a solution, something as below works for me in this question.

```
DELETE FROM a       
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM b
              WHERE b.x = a.x and b.y = a.y)
```

Comment: This is Gordon's answer. Why do you post it as yours?

Comment: Maybe I did not refresh the page.  Whatever, I found this from some other where. Does this matter? This is my question and I just post the answer that finally helped me solve it.

Comment: Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399 so you know how things work here.

Comment: OK. That is the first time I use stack overflow. I did not know these rules.